# How to use Django mixin?

Tags: python, django, django-views

In my app I have a bunch of DetailViews and ListViews. I need to add a panel with "last visited pages" info to every page. I know I can make two my own classes inheriting from DetailView and ListView respectively and overriding get_context_data method, but that will dublicate the code. At the moment I solved the problem, by simply adding one line of code to every view

```
context['panel_info'] = get_panel_info()
```

but I don't like this solution as well. 
My idea was to create a Mixin with custom get_context_data method, but as far as I know, if I inherit like this

```
class MyView(DetailView, MyMixin):
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(MyView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        return context
```

Mixin's method won't be called at all.
So what's the cleverest solution to this?

Comment: Sounds like you need a [template context processor](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/templates/api/#writing-your-own-context-processors).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are different ways to do this, if you need something reusable to all of your views then a context processor might be the solution, yet if you need it only on some specific views then a Mixin might also do the trick.
How you do it:

```
class MyMixin(object):

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(MyMixin, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['panel_info'] = get_panel_info()
        return context


class MyView(MyMixin, DetailView):
   ...
```

You don't need to override the get_context_data in your MyView for the Mixin to work.

Comment: Thank you, that worked for me. I don't understand, where I messed up first time doing the same thing. I will stick to this design, as it seems to be more clear for my case.

Comment: You messed in the class ordering (Mixin goes first then the CBV follows) :)

Comment: I tried both ways, maybe it was just sleeptime. Nethertheless it works now.

Comment: I mean in the declaration:
`class MyView(MyMixin, DetailView)`

Comment: Yes, I tried that, but messed somehting up. Perphaps I forgot to call super in the Mixin. As I got from python's documentation, in case of multiple inheritance, if both parents have same method/atribute, child uses the one of the "left most" parent. So I can call super in both parents to override such behavior and inherit the same method from both parents?

Comment: What I did not understand, shouldn't "super(MyMixin, self)" be "super(MyView, self)"? Why not?

Answer (score 1):

Like **BurhanKhalid** mentioned, using a template context processor is a clever solution. Context processors let you specify a number of variables that get set in each context automatically.

The only catch is that you need to use `RequestContext` in place of `Context`. So,

```
def my_view(request):
    return render(request, 'template.html', {'whatever': 'whatever'},
                  context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Make the context processor. Its basically a method which takes a HttpRequest and returns a dict.

```
def last_visited_pages_context_processor(request):
    # Your custom code
    return {'foo': 'bar'}
```

Now, just add the context processor to `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` in your **settings.py**,

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
'django.core.context_processors.auth',
'django.core.context_processors.debug',
'django.core.context_processors.i18n',
'django.core.context_processors.media',
'your_app.context_processors.last_visited_pages_context_processor',
)
```

Good to go. More info at http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter09.html

Comment: The main disadvantage I see is the need to override 'render_to_response' method of view classes, as generic views use Context and not the RequestContext objects by default, though it may be a good solution.